# Can a Japanese citizen get a visa for Iran at the border from Pakistan?

Tags: visas, visas-on-arrival, iran, pakistan

My Japanese friend found it impossible to get a visa for [Iran](https://wikivoyage.org/wiki/Iran) in [Tokyo](https://wikivoyage.org/wiki/Tokyo), and decided to try and get it at the border from Pakistan to Iran.

Is it even possible?
Wikivoyage says [visa on arrival](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Iran#Visa_on_arrival) is possible at the Imam Khomeini International Airport, but no mention about coming by road or train.

It would be for a two-weeks touristic stay.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My Japanese friend tried this week in Islamabad (not near the border but better than nothing), at the Consulate General of the Islamic Republic of Iran.

Conclusion: It is hard to get, but not impossible!

- The first time she tried, she was turned down.
- The second time she tried even harder, and that worked!

She paid a Rs. 5000 visa fee.

Comment: Don't hesitate to accept your own answer, since it's based on actual experience and seems more precise than all other answers provided until now.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "tried harder" means? That would likely be helpful to future readers.

Comment: @AndrewFerrier: OK I will ask her

Answer (score 5):

The site linked by Ankur gives the address and website of the Iranian embassy in Tokyo. Guess your friend didn't do his research properly:

> JAPAN (TOKYO)
>
> سفارت جمهوری اسلامی ایران - توکیو
>
> Embassy of the Islamic Republic of Iran, Tokyo, Japan
>
> Titel of Diplomatic Office:Embassy
>
> Head of Diplomatic Office:
>
> Date of Establishment:1930
>
> Address:3-10-32MINAMI-AZABU ,MINATO-KU
>
> Address:TOKYO 106 JAPAN
>
> P.O.Box:34489022
>
> Country-Area-Code:0081
>
> Tel.:033 - 34468011-34468015-34468014-34468013- 3446801
>
> Fax:033 - 34462383
>
> Emergency-Tel:
>
> Consular Section:34468021-34468023 FAX CON.3448902
>
> Homepage: tokyo.mfa.ir
>
> E-mail:SJEI@GOL.COM

Online visa applications seem to be down at the moment, but the embassy should be able to help him out. If they say he can't get a visa, I doubt he'll get one by just turning up at some dusty border checkpoint and asking (and if they let him through after paying a few hundred dollars, he's going to have trouble with the first police or other security checkpoint that asks for his papers).

Comment: I don't know the details but I am sure she has been to this embassy at least a few times already.

Comment: if the embassy can't help her, I doubt she can get a visa (but do try to contact an embassy or consulate in another country, maybe the ROK, they might have other avenues).

Answer (score 4):

According to IATA's TimaticWeb database which most airlines check visa requirements against (which I accessed through [Delta Airlines' site](http://www.delta.com/planning_reservations/plan_flight/international_travel_information/visa_passport_information/)), visa-on-arrival in Iran is available for:

> Holders of normal passports traveling as tourist can obtain   a visa on arrival, for a max. stay of 15 days, provided:
>
> - holding an e-visa pre-approval code obtained via e-mail from the Ministry of Foreign Affairs at: [www.mfa.gov.ir](http://www.mfa.gov.ir);   and
> - arriving at Chah-Bahar (ZBR), Gheshm (GSM), Kish (KIH),   Mashad, (MHD) Esfahan (IFN), Shiraz (SYZ), Tabriz (TBZ) and   Tehran Imam Khomeini International (IKA) or Tehran Mehrabad International (THR); and
> - holding a photograph, a copy of passport's biographical page and fee of between EUR 30 and EUR 80.

It would therefore seem obtaining visa-on-arrival is not possible at land borders.

Comment: I am not familiar with this IATA tool, but maybe it concentrates on airports and does not list all ways to get on-arrival visa?

Comment: There is no reason timatic would provide any info on land borders…